# Accessing source code of built-in tools of ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing

I want to see source code of built-in tool (just now "Intersect", later maybe another).

Is there any built-in function for its reading?

Comment: ArcGIS is closed source software. I fear you are out of luck.

Comment: Note sure why the down votes. Just because the answer is NO doesn't mean you need to down vote it. The question is about GIS software... If you're going to down vote, leave a note why.

Answer (score 3):

The Intersect tool and many, but far from all, parts of the ArcGIS platform are closed source so it is unlikely that you would be provided access unless you were part of the software development team responsible for the tool of interest.